# Display column from one Sharepoint list into another list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have one Sharepoint list that contains training courses and duration (in hours). I have another list where users can enter the training they have and plan to take (using a Lookup column connected to the first list)

Is there a way I can bring over that Hours column to display on the second list? I only have access to the vanilla web parts and SPD, and I am not allowed to add third-party stuff (solutions/web parts) on the SP servers.

I just need that Hours column to appear in the list itself without users needing to click the lookup field (course title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple column field type and you use that as lookup field. You can get two column values in one field. It will show up as two different columns on list but you will need render templates for input forms. Check this out for basic idea

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd727508.aspx#id0450138

- Create a field type for course list
- Create render template for MCV and extend SPFieldMultiColumnValue
- Make that field as Lookup Column

You have to check if you can do second step using SPD only. Also another way to do it is using [Multiple column lookup field](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/multiple-column-lookup-field-for-sharepoint/)

HTH

Comment: Looks great, I forgot to add that I don't need that field to appear in forms, just that column in the list. I was thinking along if some quick and dirty CEWP hacking can do it and minimize fuzzing with SPD if possible.